# JFileChooser can select any folder apart from the current one?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser to allow the user to select a folder. They must be able to view the files in each folder for context. The problem is that I can't select the folder I am when the dialog pops up. (i.e. I click "open" and nothing happens). However, if I switch to another directory and then back to the first one, then I can select it.

```
public static String selectFolder()
{
    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser() {
            public void approveSelection() {
                if (getSelectedFile().isFile()) {
                    return;
                } else
                    super.approveSelection();
            }
    };

    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Folder");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES );

    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    File x = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    if( x != null )
        return x.toString();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: not really a solution, but IMO, it is more user friendly to start at some drive and not a folder

Comment: Hi there. We don't use [solved] title hacks here - using the acceptance system is fine on its own, as you have done already. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String selectFolder() {
    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser() {
        public void approveSelection() {
            if (getSelectedFile().isFile()) {
                return;
            } else
                super.approveSelection();
        }
    };

    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Folder");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

    chooser.setSelectedFile(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File x = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    if (x != null)
        return x.toString();

    return null;
}
```

you only have to add the line:

```
chooser.setSelectedFile(new java.io.File("."));
```

for the sake of being user-friendly, set it to the same as the `CurrentDirectory`, so that the user sees which directory will be selected when he clicks the button

Comment: That does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per JFileChooser you have to choose a file or folder on the dialog then only it will allow you to click open/save.

Comment: So how do you choose the directory which the dialog points to when it is first opened? Switch to a different directory and then switch back to the first one?